# mySQL: join not finding data, even though they exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a couple of tables in a mySQL database. For simplicity I'll just show some basic fields:

Table: **sources**:

```
sourceID int not null unique primary key
trigger int not null
<other stuff>
```

Table: **sourceBS**

```
id not null unique primary key
sourceID int not null,
name varchar(20),
```

`SourceID` in the in the **sourceBS** table is a foreign key referencing its namesake in sources, with the cascade option. I have tested this: if I delete an entry in sources, the corresponding entry in sourceBS also vanishes. Good.

I want to select some stuff from a join of **sources** and **sourceBS**, filtering based on a "sources" property. This should be easy, via a join which, I think, the foreign key should render pretty efficient, so:

```
SELECT sources.sourceID, sourceBS.* 
FROM sources 
LEFT JOIN sourceBS ON sources.sourceID = sourceBS.sourceID 
WHERE trigger=1;
```

But when this runs, each row has "`NULL`" for the values returned from **sourceBS**, even **sourceBS** contains entries matching the condition. I can verify this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sourceBS 
WHERE sourceID IN (
    SELECT sourceID 
    FROM sources 
    WHERE trigger=1
);
```

Here I get a proper set of results, i.e. non-null values. But, while this works as a proof of concept, it's no good in real life because I want to return a bunch of stuff from the "sources" table as well, and I don't want to have to run multiple queries in order to get what I want.

Returning to the join, if I replace the left join with an inner join, then no results are returned. It is as if, somehow, the "join" is simply not finding any matches in the sourceBS table, and yet they are there as the second query shows.

Why is this happening? I know that this join has a 1:M relationship, sourceBS could have multiple entries for a given entry in sources, but that should be OK. I can test exactly this type of join on other DBs, and it works.

Comment: Provide [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: include sample data so that problem can be re-producible.

Comment: I have created a SQL Fiddle that should encapsulate what the OP wants, but the issue doesn't seem to occur. [See Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6631ae/6)

Comment: @Phil Evans:- you have to know, if you ask question then show proof that what is not working with some minimal re-producible example. so that community can help you to resolve this. Dont just post question with state "this is not working" without any example

Comment: query is fine. It may be you don't have any matching information in your tables. Provide some sample values you really have in your db and that you expect they should return as the result

Comment: Thanks folks. I wasn't aware of SQLfiddle. I've now created an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1212a/1 and it works. So I'm REALLY confused. Opening a new mySQL connection to my main DB it also works(!) Maybe some transaction/concurrency issue I guess? (Although I'm sure everything was committed....) Anyway, thanks for confirming my syntax was OK, and sorry to waste your time on what looks like a user issue. I will remember SQLfiddle from now on though!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've solved this - it wasn't a transaction issue in the end:when I tried it on the original machine, it failed again. It was the order of the join. It appears that in my terminal I had the "ON" clause the other way round to above, that is, I was doing:

```
... LEFT JOIN sourceBS ON (sourceBS.blockSourceID=sources.sourceID)
```

which returns all the nulls. If I do it (as in the above code I pasted)

```
... LEFT JOIN sourceBS ON (sources.sourceID=sourceBS.sourceID
```

it works. When I tried it the second time last night on a new machine, I'd used the second formulation.

Guess I'd better read up on joins to understand why this happened!